# Microsoft SSRS 2012 Report Manager - HTTP 500 error (The website cannot display the page),while Report Server fine

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportserver, reportmanager

I have a situation in which my Microsoft SSRS 2012 Report Server works fine, but not the Report Manager, which
 throws HTTP 500 error (The website cannot display the page).

SSRS 2012 Report Manager and Report Server were working fine until yesterday, when I successfully
 installed SQL Server 2016 with SSRS; SSRS 2016 Report Server and Report Manager are fine; so do my
 SSRS 2008R2 Report Server and Report Manager.  (I had both SSRS 2008R2 and SSRS 2012 working fine
 just before the successful installation of SSRS 2016; now the Report Manager part of SSRS 2012 is 
not working, others stay intact)

I think SQL Server 2012 was installed as default instance almost a year back.

---

Details from SSRS 2012 Reporting Services Configuration Manager:

Service Account: Use Built-in account  (ReportServer$SQL2012DEV)

---

Details from  SSRS 2016 and SSRS 2008R2 Reporting Services Configuration Manager:

Service Account: Use Built-in account (Network Service)

---

I have the screen shot of the Reporting Services Configuration Manager.
[image]

Below is the screenshot from SQL Server Configuration Manager:[image]

This is taken from the Event Viewer-Windows Log-Application:  Source    ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0

```html
Failed to initialize the AppDomain:ReportManager_SQL2012DEV_0

Exception: System.Web.HttpException

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

StackTrace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)

InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

StackTrace:    at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()

InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

StackTrace:    at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)

InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

StackTrace:
```

This is taken from the SSRS logs: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQL2012DEV\Reporting Services\LogFiles\ReportingServerService.txt

```html
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)


   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(String appId, Type type, IApplicationHost appHost, Boolean failIfExists, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObject(String appId, Type type, String virtualPath, String physicalPath, Boolean failIfExists, Boolean throwOnError)
   at ReportingServicesHttpRuntime.RsHttpRuntime.Create(RsAppDomainType type, String vdir, String pdir, Int32& domainId)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
appdomainmanager!ReportManager_0-29!3c3c!03/09/2017-14:41:13:: i INFO: Appdomain:31 ReportManager_SQL2012DEV_0-29-131335242724582365 unloading
library!DefaultDomain!3c3c!03/09/2017-14:41:13:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerAppDomainManagerException: Failed to create Report Server HTTP Runtime, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerAppDomainManagerException: An error occurred when attempting to start the application domain ReportManager within the Report Server service. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeInternalException: An internal or system error occurred in the HTTP Runtime object for application domain ReportManager_SQL2012DEV_0.  ---> System.Web.HttpException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.ObjectModel' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
rshost!rshost!3c3c!03/09/2017-14:41:13:: e ERROR: Failed to create HttpRuntime 80131500.
rshost!rshost!3c3c!03/09/2017-14:41:13:: e ERROR: Failed to get appdomain 80131500, pipeline=0x00000002781A5990.
rshost!rshost!3c3c!03/09/2017-14:41:13:: e ERROR: Error state. Internal abort for pipeline=0x00000002781A5990 ...
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!3240!03/09/2017-14:41:19:: i INFO: Appdomain:31 ReportManager_SQL2012DEV_0-29-131335242724582365 unregistered.
rshost!rshost!3240!03/09/2017-14:41:19:: i INFO: Application domain type ReportManager statistics: created: 27, unloaded: 27, failed: 0, timed out: 0.
```

Comment: Any suggestion please ?  I am yet to hear anything in the last 3 days from any of you.   I need to get this sorted out ASAP; I have my SSRS 2012 Report Server working still, and am using it temporarily to show the reports to our client; but I need to get the SSRS 2012 Report Manager working ultimately.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue when multiple versions of SSRS is installed on the same environment. In my system, I have installed SQL 2012, SQL 2014 & SQL 2016 including SSRS and other shared features.

SSRS 2012 instance doesn't include any SharePoint components. However, it appears that Report Manager of SSRS 2012 was referring them from another instance. I came to know about it during checking of log files generated at *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\\Reporting Services\LogFiles*.

**Solution:**

I have verified all installed SQL instance specific components and Shared components.

I have identified that SQL 2012 and SQL 2014 instances don't contain any component pertaining to SharePoint. But, SQL 2016 instance contains few shared components pertaining to SharePoint. They were **"Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RS Add-in for SharePoint"** and **"Reporting Services - SharePoint"**.

Under Programs & Features from Control Panel, I uninstalled **"Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RS Add-in for SharePoint"** component. I stopped and restarted the SSRS services for both 2012 and 2016 instances. After this, Report Manager of SSRS 2012 was still not working.

Next, under Programs & Features from Control Panel, I selected "**Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (64-bit)**", and selected **Uninstall/Change**, and selected remove. Navigating through, I got to the Select Features page. Under Shared Features, I checked **"Reporting Services - SharePoint"** and proceed to remove it.

Upon completion, I restarted the SSRS services for both SQL 2012 and 2016 instances. After this, both of the SSRS sites for 2012 and 2016 instances are working as expected. So my issue is resolved.

I am still not clear why a setting or feature inclusion of SQL 2016 instance was affecting SQL 2012 instance.

Answer (score -1):

it just works after removing below tag fro the file:-

machine.config